# Idiom that describes a person who doesn't have an acceptable witness

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

We Persians have a proverb that says:

> They asked the fox, "Who's your witness?" The fox said, "My tail!"

What do Americans say when a person only has their ally as a witness? Is there any idiom for this?

Comment: If you call the ally a *henchman*, *lackey*, *toady*, or *yes-man*, then everyone would know the witness is not to be trusted. A so-labeled ally will be assumed to say whatever the other person wants him to say.

Comment: "Unreliable witness" & "dubious witness" are two adjectives often used. However, there are _many_ reasons a witness may be considered unreliable – not just because they are an ally to the accused – so they don't completely answer your query.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any relevant idioms, but [unvouched-for](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unvouched) would be understood by all native speakers. Depending on the exact context, maybe *uncorroborated*, or *unsubstantiated* might fit better.

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic phrase, albeit one with multiple meanings, is *in his back pocket*.  This is the sense used in headlines like [Romney Has Drudge Report In “Back Pocket”, Says Thompson](http://www.webpronews.com/romney-has-drudge-2012-01) and [Top Senate Democrat Tacitly Acknowledges He Has Angus King’s Vote In His Back Pocket](http://www.nrsc.org/2012/04/top-senate-democrat-tacitly-acknowledges-he-has-angus-kings-vote-in-his-back-pocket-state-democrats-question-kings-record-while-washington-democrats-stand-ready-to-welcome-him-with/).  *Note:* As suggested in a comment about *[in one's pocket](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pocket)* referring to *in one's control or possession*, it appears that *pocket* alone (without *back*) is also suitable.  For example, "Witness *X* is in *Y*'s pocket" (or back pocket) means *X* may be a suborned witness. *Note 2: [American Expressions](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2ggDZDRh8fEC&pg=PA31&dq=%22have+him+in+my+hip+pocket%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1ZDVT_CRM9CdmQXp7qyKAw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22have%20him%20in%20my%20hip%20pocket%22&f=false)* 
by Billy R. Lawson lists "I have him in my hip pocket" as meaning "He owes me some favors".

Besides some terms previously mentioned, also consider *[perjurer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perjurer)*, *[cover story](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cover_story)* (in sense "A fictitious account that is intended to hide one's real motive"), and *paid witness*.

*Note:* Regarding already-suggested *no alibi*, from time to time one hears phrases like [Alibi Al](http://opinion.latimes.com/opinionla/2007/07/alibi-al.html) applied to alibied persons, and  [Alibi Guy](http://www.alibiguy.com/uncategorized/alibi-guy-episode-1-free-prizes-enter-the-alibi-for-george-contest) applied to people supplying alibis (alibiers?).

Comment: M-W agrees with my understanding that [in one's pocket](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pocket) means *in one's control or possession*. But I don't know that inserting the word *"back"* conveys any special nuance that might be understood by many people.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks, I've added some of that to answer.  While *back* may not be needed or may add little, it's been part of the idiom as I've encountered it.

Comment: Google Books claims 2020 instances of ["have him in my pocket"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+him+in+my+pocket%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but only 6 of ["have him in my **back** pocket"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+him+in+my+back+pocket%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Perhaps it's a regionalism, or a modern "journalese" usage that hasn't made it into print much yet.

Comment: In one's pocket is very close. But the proverb that I said means that the witness benefits from the situation so other people doubt his or her words. _no mention of suborn_

Answer (score 2):

Referring to someone as having "no [alibi](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alibi?s=t)" is said so much that it is *almost* an expression, I should think.

Comment: Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary:
**alibi**
`1.   evidence that proves that a person was in another place at the time of a crime and so could not have committed it 
The suspects all had alibis for the day of the robbery.   
2.   an excuse for sth that you have done wrong. `
According to these definitions I don't think that we can use alibi in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In such a case it could be said that the witness was 'in his ally's corner' or that the witness 'had his friend's back'.  In the first case the implication is that the witness would tailor his evidence to support his ally; in the second that while the witness would support his friend through thick and thin he may not be prepared to bend the truth in so doing.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is that the English language has no idiom I have ever encountered that describes the person who does not have an independent witness for him.

As others have offered, we do have *plenty* of idioms to describe the person who is the tail. Just not the fox.